# Loop over "history" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

Is there a way to loop over the "history" object in javascript to find a specific page in the history?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Security reasons - no, you can not dump the history of the browser (with javascript)

I mean you can not do

```
// This does not work
for (i=0; i<window.history.length; i++) {
      alert(window.history[i]);
}
```

However I don't have good explanation why `history.go(n);` is ok

Comment: `history.go(n)` is ok because it doesn't give you any information about the users history... it only sends them back to that location.

Comment: What about the properties current, next and previous ? can't they reveal the URLs ? Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please clarify my question ? Thanks!

Comment: No, those properties are no longer available to web scripting in any browser. `history.go()` isn't a security problem, but it's certainly a usability problem and should never be used.

Comment: @bobince "should never be used"?  What about a single page Web application which uses hash browsing and the history for navigation?  Never is too strong a word.  There are legitimate uses but its use should be considered carefully.

Answer (score 11):

No, because it would you the ability to basically spy on the web history of anyone visiting your site (you could send this information to your server using Javascript).

You can redirect the client to particular pages in their history using the Javascript history object's [back(), forward(), and go() methods](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javahistory.html).  You just can't know where exactly you're redirecting them (except in the case of using go() to redirect to a URL instead of a history number).

Comment: At least reading the history within the current Same-Origin-Policy scope would be nice ;-)

Comment: @user3651406 I agree. Lame that you can not manipulate duplicate record for history on the domain and website you want control over.